# Rails production.log file is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 2.3.13 and in my `environments/production.rb`, I have:

```
config.log_level = :info
RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER = SyslogLogger.new('mysite-platform-production')
```

Yet my `log/production.log` is empty. Why would that be?

Comment: You're not logging anything?

Comment: Shouldn't there at least be the routes that were hit in the log?

Comment: Is the appropriate permissions to write given to `log/production.log` ?

Comment: `-rw-rw-rw- 1 www-data www-data      0 2012-05-02 18:52 production.log` - yes. looks to be appropriate permissions

Comment: Did you launch the app server with the production flag? Also, is that second line supposed to redirect your logging to that file?

Comment: The server is launched with production. I know that because of other environment settings (like DB). I'm not sure what that second line is supposed to do, to be honest. Looks like it's some third party gem.

Comment: That line looks like it rerouting the to that file. Have you checked to see if the logs are appearing there? Or tried removing it and restarting?

Comment: What server are you running?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are instantiating a `SyslogLogger`, so your logging will go into the syslog (in most cases available as a file in */var/log/syslog* on Unix systems) and not into a logfile. The parameter you pass to the logger (*mysite-platform-production*) is the identifier used by syslog and not a filename.

If you want to log to a file in your log directory, you have to set up your logger as follows:

```
RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER = Logger.new('log/production.log')
```

**But:** I am pretty sure that you don't actually have to do that explicitly but that it is done by default by Rails, so I suggest just not setting `RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER` in your code and you should get a logger that logs into *log/production.log* implicitly...

Comment: I have 4 different instances of this machine running and it's behind an AWS load balancer - so I'm not sure where the log is writing at all

Comment: The logging goes to the syslog of each individual machine. The syslog daemon then most probably logs it into a file (*/var/log/syslog*), but it could also be configured to forward it to another machine for example... See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog for more informations about syslog.

Comment: But back to your question: where would you like your log entries to go to? To a file in the app directory on each machine?

Answer (score -1):

Given how you set the logger, you should find a file named 'mysite-platform-production', **not production.log**, and it will be **on the root directory** of your project. If you want to find it in 'log/mysite-platform-production.log' you will have to do:

```
RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER = SyslogLogger.new('log/mysite-platform-production.log')
```

Comment: The syslog logger does **not** log to a file, it just sends the logs to the local syslog daemon which then decides on its own where to write or send the logs to. The parameter in the logger initialization does not specify a file path.