# Rails App production.log shows empty

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, vps, unicorn

I have deploy Rails App on VPS [Nginx + Unicorn].
After starting the server , generated log are not written in log files.
It shows Empty.

Can any one suggest ,why log file is empty.

Comment: Be more specific. What logs (nginx/production)? Please attach your config.
[How to deploy a Rails app with unicorn and nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: rails app log inside log directory

Comment: Did you read this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210625/rails-production-log-file-is-empty)?

Comment: Which Rails version are you using?

Comment: See the answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180690/set-logging-levels-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Rails -v is 4.2.5, log is generated in production.log on local machine when run in production mode, but same is not getting replicated in the VPS.still file size is zero only, file has proper access right require to write logs.